# Confusion over the representation of a curl of a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis, curl

Learning vector calculus and I'm still confused over what the curl represents for a vector field. It is stated that the curl represents the magnitude of rotation of surrounding vectors to a given point. But which direction does it point?

Let's say we were to use the field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\langle-y,x,0\rangle$, which gives us the velocity vector of a particle moving on the path $x^2+y^2=r^2$ with speed $r$ counter-clockwise on the x-y plane with the plane translated upwards for any $z$.

Intuitively by the argument of rotation, we have circular rotation over any point on the z-axis with the same axis of rotation, while for any other point there doesn't appear to be the same circular behavior surrounding that point, so I would expect the curl to return a different quantity.

Yet we obtain

$$\nabla\times\vec{F}=\langle0,0,2\rangle$$

a constant vector for any point. If the behavior of the vector field around a point is different for points on the z-axis and any other point, yet the curl yields the same vector, what exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you put an object in this field (just for simplicity, suppose it's a thin bar), then it would experience rotation at the same rate, no matter where it is placed.  It's this local rotation-causing torque we're measuring with the curl.

The field may also cause the object to travel in a circle, but that isn't itself what the curl measures, even though you can use an integral to connect the two phenomena.

Comment: By object, do you mean a point particle? Or an object of some finite but small size? Because if the latter wouldn't it mean that it would deform with the field? What is meant by rotation?

Comment: @AnsonPang Someone might be able to explain how to apply torque to a point particle, but I can't.  The object, as I amended, should be something like a thin bar.  In my mind, I imagine a thin rod of balsa wood, or something like that.  I'm not sure why you are saying the object must deform... when I experience wind which is stronger on my head than on my feet, I don't just deform, but rather it may knock me over.

Comment: Rotation is, in the sense we care about here, the spin of an object about its center of mass.  I hope that suffices.

Comment: So I assume it just gives us some relative quantification of how much spin we would get out of an object placed at different points. Where a vector with bigger magnitude corresponds to more spin to be expected, but that there isn't some precise mathematical computation as to why we would obtain that particular vector with said magnitude besides taking the curl formula as it is.

Comment: @AnsonPang There is a precise reason why the formula is what it is: It's so that it satisfies $\int_{\partial D}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_D \operatorname{curl}(F)\cdot \vec{n}\,dA$.  When you use a small rectangle for $D$ and assume a certain level of smoothness, the given formula for the curl of $F$ drops out.  Then it's just a matter of showing the same formula extends to a sufficiently broad set of $D$s.